# Dialog box apearing in the main window

Tags: tkinter, dialog

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


class menu():
  def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master  
    master.title('Library Management Software')
    master.geometry('1230x650')
    master.configure(background="#98ff98")
    master.iconbitmap("e:\library\image\save.ico")#adding icon on title window
    menubar = Menu(master)
    membermenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    membermenu.add_command(label = "Member" , command = self.reg_window)
    menubar.add_cascade(label = "Entry", menu = membermenu)
    master.config(menu = menubar)
  def reg_window(self):
    self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
    self.app = registration_window(self.newWindow)

class registration_window(Toplevel):
  def __init__(self, master):
    
    self.master=master  
    #self.transient(master)
    master.title('Registration Form')
    master.geometry('1230x650')
    master.configure(background="#98ff98")
    master.iconbitmap("e:\library\image\save.ico")#adding icon on title window
    item_file = StringVar()
    image_label = Label(master, text="Photo: ", bg="gray74", relief="groove")
    image_label.place(x=755,y=150)
                 
    item_entry = Entry(master, textvariable=item_file,width=35)
    item_entry.place(x=795,y=150)
    self.item_button = Button(master, text="\uD83D\uDCC2", relief="groove",
                             command=lambda:entry_set(item_entry, askopenfilename()))
    self.item_button.place(x=1000, y=150, height=20, width=20)
    def entry_set(entry, text):
      item_entry.delete(0, 'end')
      item_entry.insert(END, text)

    




def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = menu(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sir, I am learning tkinter for a couple of months and my problem is that i cannot understand where i will use this statement **self.transient(master)** so that when my the dialog box appear on the registration window
where i will use transient statement in my code

Comment: actually what i believe what `transient(...)` does is, it creates a window but as the name suggests, its temporary. The window wont be shown in the taskbar

Comment: and what exactly do you want the `filedialog` to do

Comment: actually when want to open a filedialog box from my second window. The dialog box appear on the first window.  this is my problem

Comment: what part of `filedialog`, like wat do u want it for, asking directory or filename ?

Comment: i want to open a image file and i want to capture the path in a entry widget

Comment: so you should be using `messagebox.askopenfilename(....)`

Comment: @CoolCloud: no, `transient` does not create a window. It marks an existing window as transient.

Comment: self.item_button = Button(master, text="\uD83D\uDCC2", relief="groove",
                             command=lambda:entry_set(item_entry, askopenfilename()))
    self.item_button.place(x=1000, y=150, height=20, width=20)

Comment: Through this statement i want to capture the file path. But when open dialog box appear over the root window not form the window where i am clicking

Comment: what is the name of the window you expect it to come at

Answer (score 1):

The dialog function accepts a `parent` option. From the documentation:

> Makes window the logical parent of the file dialog. The file dialog is
> displayed on top of its parent window. On Mac OS X, this turns the
> file dialog into a sheet attached to the parent window.

Typically, in a class that inherits from `Toplevel` you would use `self`. However, you're not using inheritance correctly so that won't work without rewriting that class. So first, we need to rewrite that class.

The first thing to do is to call the `__init__` method of the superclass. That is the secret sauce that makes your `registration_window` an actual `Toplevel` window.

```
class registration_window(Toplevel):
  def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)
    ...
```

Next, you need to remove all other uses of `self.master` or `master` and instead use `self` so that all of the widgets are inside itself. In addition, add `parent=self` when you call `askopenfilename`. The class should look like this:

```
class registration_window(Toplevel):
  def __init__(self, master):

    super().__init__(master)
    self.title('Registration Form')
    self.geometry('1230x650')
    self.configure(background="#98ff98")
    self.iconbitmap("e:\library\image\save.ico")#adding icon on title window
    item_file = StringVar()
    image_label = Label(self, text="Photo: ", bg="gray74", relief="groove")
    image_label.place(x=755,y=150)

    item_entry = Entry(self, textvariable=item_file,width=35)
    item_entry.place(x=795,y=150)
    self.item_button = Button(self, text="yes, this button", relief="groove",
                             command=lambda:entry_set(item_entry, askopenfilename(parent=self)))
    self.item_button.place(x=1000, y=150, height=20, width=100)
    def entry_set(entry, text):
      item_entry.delete(0, 'end')
      item_entry.insert(END, text)
```

Finally, to use this class you don't need to create another `Toplevel`. Change `reg_window` to look like this:

```
def reg_window(self):
  self.app = registration_window(self.master)
```